# Python script using OpenPyxl generates InvalidFileException

Tags: python, xlsx, openpyxl

I am trying to read an .xlsx file using the following Python script:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = r'20140623_082919_40414068.xlsx')
sheet_ranges = wb['range names']
print sheet_ranges['D18'].value
```

But I keep getting the following error message:

> File "/home/kofi/Dropbox/openexample.py", line 29, in 
> wb = load_workbook(filename = r'20140623_082919_40414068.xlsx')
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py",
> line 168, in load_workbook
>
> raise InvalidFileException(unicode(e))
> openpyxl.exceptions.InvalidFileException:
>
> "There is no item named 'xl/styles.xml' in the archive"

Is there anyway to fix the Excel file? These are files that will be sent to me daily and I would not be able to fix what is sent to me.

Comment: What openpyxl version are you using? Are you okay with switching to `xlrd` (looks like there are `xls` excel files)?

Comment: I am using the latest Openpyxl file and there was an error it is a xlsx file. I tried xlrd and had a similar error.

Comment: While editing your question, the last paragraph got my attention: You are asking if there's a way to fix the Excel file, but then you say that you can't alter the files sent to you - do you see the inconsistency?

Comment: Yes I do. Is there a way to manipulate the file before reading it with openpyxl?

Comment: Do you mean manipulate an Excel file **without** changing its contents?

Comment: Yes in order to get rid of the error message I am getting above.

Comment: Or if there is a issue in my code to remove the error message.

Comment: `styles.xml` is a necessary part of any `.xlsx` file which is just a zip archive. You might be able to create a workaround by adding such a file to the archive before you load it in openpyxl.

Comment: Yes I also thought of that any idea on how I would do that?

Comment: Easy enough. Take the styles.xml from an an existing Excel archive and copy into the new ones. You can do this in Python with the `zipfile` module.

Comment: See also this answer on a related question. It's probably due to a bug in openpyxl, for which there is a fix.